# How to explore elements in a nested boolean list and get aggregated scores?

Tags: python

Hello this is a pretty simple question but i wanted to follow the dry principles correctly and couldn't think of a way to do it without repeating code

so given game outcomes in this format

`game outcome = [['wins', 'loses'], ['loses', 'wins'], ['loses', 'wins']]`

the gameoutcome[0][0] till gameoutcome[2][0] are all user game outcomes so for that paticular user he won and lost 2 whereas the computer won twice but lost once

what i want to do is aggregate the users out comes  and the computer outcomes based on the number of wins then finally in this scenario

```
if(computer_outcome > user_outcome):
   computer wins
else 
  user wins
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you get the 2 results:

```py
game_outcome = [['wins', 'loses'], ['loses', 'wins'], ['loses', 'wins']]
user_outcome = sum([i[0] == 'wins' for i in game_outcome])
computer_outcome = sum([i[1] == 'wins' for i in game_outcome])
```

Comment: You can actually remove the `[` and `]` in your `sum` call, it will make a generator instead of a list, which will not allocate, and therefore be faster.

Comment: You also don't need to calculate _both_ `user_outcome` and `computer_outcome` by running the loop again, since one is simply `len(game_outcome) - the other`. This only applies when every game is win/lose, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Should you have only 2 possible outcomes, you can skip the second calculation:

```py
game_outcomes = [['wins', 'loses'], ['loses', 'wins'], ['loses', 'wins']]
user_wins = sum(item[0] == 'wins' for item in game_outcomes)
computer_wins = len(game_outcomes) - user_wins
```